# Splitting columns and getting new table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datatable

I have a table like this in postgresql:

```
Time  | id/type  | value

1        A/a       10
2        A/b       15
3        A/c       8
4        A/b       2
```

And I want to convert into a new_table with layout:

```
Time  | id  | a  | b  | c

1      A   10    Null   Null 
2      A   Null  15     Null
3      A   Null  Null    8
4      A   Null  2      Null
```

Could you please help me on this problem? I am quite new to Sql in general, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CASE expression for each column:

```
select "Time", split_part("id/type", '/', 1) id,
  case when split_part("id/type", '/', 2) = 'a' then "value" end a,
  case when split_part("id/type", '/', 2) = 'b' then "value" end b,
  case when split_part("id/type", '/', 2) = 'c' then "value" end c
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfMoNcps6te2dWa8j3EM2s/0).
Results:

```
| Time | id  | a   | b   | c   |
| ---- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1    | A   | 10  |     |     |
| 2    | A   |     | 15  |     |
| 3    | A   |     |     | 8   |
| 4    | A   |     | 2   |     |
```